# How to add/get Sprite to/from UIComponent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, sprite

How to add Sprite to BorderContainer (UIComponent)?

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.lineStyle(10,0);
sprite.graphics.moveTo(40,40);
sprite.graphics.lineTo(60,60);          

mybordercontainer.addChild(sprite);   
//mybrodercontainer is id of BorderContainer created in mxml
```

This code doesnt work. I cant see Sprite on my BorderContainer. How can I add Sprites on UIComponents, so I can see them? I tried this and it kinda worked:

```
var comp:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
comp.addChild(sprite);
myborderconteiner.addElement(comp);
```

But I dont think, that this is a right way to add Sprites to UIComponents. Is there another method to do that?

---

Second problem:

When I have few Sprites added to my UIComponent (lines/circles/images or others) how can I receive an object Sprite from that UIComponent, which is containing all Sprites added before to that UIComponent?

I need to create Bitmap from that Sprite and do some things.

I hope I make myself clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SpriteVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html) as container. That should serve nicely as a container or Sprite substitute. You could also draw in the UIComponent itself.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. I replaced my BorderContainer with SpriteVisualElement and it works exactly as I wanted. I can easily convert them to BitMap. Thank you